# Laravel 5: Why Class 'App\Console\Commands\SSH' not found?

Tags: ssh, laravel-5

I'm following instructions on 
https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/ssh
in order to use SSH to perform SFTP download from a private server.

I've done so far:

```
$> composer require laravelcollective/remote
```

added in config app :

```
'providers' => [
....
Collective\Remote\RemoteServiceProvider::class,
...
]
'aliases' => [
....
'SSH' => Collective\Remote\RemoteFacade::class,
...
]
```

published it:

```
$> php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Collective\Remote\RemoteServiceProvider"
```

Then I also run a composer update

But still in my console command if I test it like:

```
$contents = SSH::into('production')->getString('/hi.txt');
dd($contents);
```

I get the error in my question.

When a service provider is defined like above, the class is globally accessible? Or still I need to put the directive use Path/to/Class ?
If so, since the Alias ahas a different name from the real classname, how should I specify the use path directive?

```
 use Collective\Remote\RemoteServiceProvider
```

or

```
 use Collective\Remote\RemoteServiceProvider
```

?

What am I missing?... I've tested other preconfigured services that comes with laravel 5.2 fresh install (i.e. Redis) and they seems to be found without any additional use directive in class.....

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just use it as global class \SSH and it will work.

```
$contents = \SSH::into('production')->getString('/hi.txt');
dd($contents);
```